# How to correctly align the layout of the Emacs Calendar after changing some faces ?

Tags: emacs, configuration, calendar

I'm trying to customize my Emacs/OrgMode and I face an alignment's problem when using the calendar. See the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHlgw.png)

I tried to customize some `calendar-*` variables such as the
`calendar-intermonth-spacing`, `calendar-intermonth-header` or `calendar-column-width` but these change did not help.

Is it always possible to get a correct alignment in the calendar view?

Comment: Can You customize to a monospace font?

Comment: this do it thanks. I assume there must be a way to only change the face in the calendar view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the function `face-remap-add-relative`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

Here is an example:

```lisp
(defun set-buffer-to-courier ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'default '(:family "Courier" :height 120)))

(add-hook 'calendar-mode-hook 'set-buffer-to-courier)
```

Comment: Indeed font in the calendar should be monospaced and this calendar hook solved the issue thanks